# Copy data efficiencly from a video tag to a webAssembly function

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, webgl, webassembly

I'm trying to do take the input from a webcam (via getUserMedia) and process it in a WebAssembly function.  The process is like this:

I have two HTML elements, a `video` and a `canvas`.

```js
// get references to the elements
const vid = document.getElementById('vid');
const canv = document.getElementById('canv');

// load the video from a connected webcam
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:false});
vid.source.srcObject = stream;

// configure the canvas to have the same dimensions
const settings = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings();
canv.width = settings.width;
canv.height = settings.height;
```

I also have a (placeholder) WebAssembly function built from some simple C code:

```
int SumPixels( unsigned char *data, size_t size ) {
  int r=0;
  for (size_t i=0; i < size; i++) {
    r+=*data++;
  }
  return r;
}
```

This has been build using emscriptem and has been loaded into a global `Module` object. When initialising I also need to reserve some shared memory

```js
//reserve memory to use as a frame buffer
const len = canv.width*canv.height*4;
const pMem = Module._malloc(len);
const mem = new UInt8Array(Module.HEAP8.buffer, pMem, len);
```

Finally, periodically using `requestAnimationFrame` I do the following

```js
      const context = canv.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
      const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
      const {data, width, height} = imageData;
      // copy data to reserved memory
      mem.set(data);
      // instead of an array, pass a pointer to the heap position of the data
      const pixSum = Module._SumPixels(pMem,len);
```

This works, however it is slow.  5fps with a full HD input.  Profiling in chrome the slow step is `getImageData` taking most of the time.

Now, IF I had a webgl canvas, I could do the following:

```js
  const gl = canv.getContext('webgl');

  //Do something to copy from the video element to the webgl canvas

  gl.readPixels(0,0,gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, mem);
  const pixSum = Module._SumPixels(pMem,len);
```

When cleaning up, always free the WASM module memory used

```js
Module._free(pMem);
mem=null;
```

the webgl steps are fast, and it copies directly into the WASM memory which is really nice, however there is no equivalent I can see to copy the data from the `video` element to the `canvas` (and it is not possible to access a canvas via both a webgl and a 2d context).

So, the question is, is there a way to efficiently copy frames from a video tag into a webgl canvas?  Or is there another way to do this to efficiently get camera frames from a video tag to a web assembly compiled function?

Comment: texImage2d accepts <video> but 200ms for getImageData is a bug. Chrome did mess up recently with their getImageData perfs, but they improved it a bit since then and it was never *that* slow. Also you can very well draw a webgl on a 2d context and vice versa.

Comment: getImageData is slow period. It has to freeze the GPU which means it has to freeze the GPU process which means cross process sychronization. It then can call `gl.readPixels` behind the scenes, copy that data from the GPU process to the render process so it can put the results in a `Uint8ClampedArray`. That's a slow process. Currently there is no fast path from video to canvas or WebGL at the moment. Many have been proposed, none have been implemented.

Comment: See the proposed section of the [extension list](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/)

Comment: @Kaiido can you explain your last comment? On a canvas once I have got a 2d context, requesting a webgl context returns null and vice-versa. Am I missing something?

Comment: I said to draw a 2d context on a webgl one, 2 canvases.

Comment: The main question aside, note that you must not do the "copy data to the start of the heap" part. This is corrupting memory and potentially overwriting data of other parts of the program, not to mention Emscripten's own checks. If you ran this code in debug mode with -s ASSERTIONS, Emscripten would warn you about this.

Instead, you need to allocate memory of corresponding size using malloc, write only to that allocated section and share the pointer between JS and Wasm parts.

Comment: @RReverser thanks. I had wondered about that, but I had not come across an example doing it. With the demo so far there is no other code using the space, however that will change. I'll add it to the code above.

Comment: > With the demo so far there is no other code using the space
You can't know that. Just because you're not using it explicitly in your own code, it doesn't mean that the linked libraries or Emscripten itself don't use that space (and Emscripten definitely uses space near address 0, hence the ASSERTIONS suggestion).

Comment: @RReverser fair point.  Changes made to use `_malloc` and a comment to use `_free` at the end.  One thing I noticed was that the malloc and free methods were not always available on the Module object, even though some of the docs indicated that they should always be.  The documentation on WASM seems rather inconsistant right now.

Comment: @EuanSmith Definitely feel free to submit an issue about the docs on Emscripten (or where you found it). It's definitely not treated in a special way and isn't guaranteed to be exported unless you add it to `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`. (otherwise it still might be implicitly exported sometimes, but depends on the usage and isn't guaranteed)

Comment: Not an answer to the question but I want to say that I was wrong about no fast path from video to webgl. Chrome will try, if possible, to render the video into a texture via the GPU behind the scenes. There is no guarantee it will take that fast path since it has to be able to fallback to slower paths if it can't take the fast path but a fast path does exist.

Comment: Have you some updates for your post?

Comment: Hi @Alexufo - I should really provide an answer.   Unfortunately the answer will be somewhat long, but in short - the first option has got faster, so just going with that is probably OK.  Yes you can get a video stream into a webgl canvas - 1. create a texture, 2. set the texture from the HTML element, 3. read the pixels.  Specifying how to do these steps will probably be long as webgl is very verbose.  Anyway, when I have the chance, I will provide an answer.

Comment: If you are wanting to do this, I suggest having a look at the twgl framework - it is a fairly thin wrapper on webgl, but takes away a lot of the verbosity. https://twgljs.org/

Comment: @EuanSmith today we have offscreencanvas (shared canvas between main thread and worker) and WebCodec to get image directly  from video without canvas.

Comment: An offscreencanvas _is_ a canvas.  I'm image processing in webassembly, so an array of image data is still required., and a canvas, offscreen or not, is still needed.  If all you are doing is showing a video and doing CSS transforms, then a video tag is enough.  This is not what I'm talking about here.

Comment: @EuanSmith we can use now more effective api to reading image stream from video source (I suppose) with web codecs
https://web.dev/webcodecs/

Comment: @Alexufo webcodecs does look really interesting.  There is still the same issue of reading/writing to/from the GPU memory - it is intended to work via ImageBitmaps which are handles to image data held in graphics memory - these can be efficiently drawn onto canvases or used as webgl textures, but a canvas (which is the core JS interface to the GPU) is still required to get the pixel data.

Comment: @EuanSmith parsing video to wasm is your bottleneck? I suppose it is fast enough.

Comment: @EuanSmith What about reading video into webGL texture and send texture directly into wasm? I have read some discussion about sending texture directly into wasm like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086424/create-textures-in-javascript-and-webgl-and-identify-them-in-webassembly), but haven't tried myself

Comment: Looked into that - after digging through the emscripten code, they deal with wasm access to webgl using javascript functions.  All emscripten is doing is hiding that detail from you.  As it happens we did get all of this working fast, and I need to answer this one properly, it is just fairly involved and I need to make the time to do so.  Ultimately it is video -> webgl texture -> (some webgl pre-processing) -> data copy to wasm -> c++ processing -> back to webgl -> capture back into video stream. whole thing done in 8ms per frame.  When I have time I'll write the answer.