# Is it possible to share a WebGL context between JavaScript and WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, webgl, webassembly

I have a web app that uses JavaScript/WebGL. It loads shaders and textures and updates and draws a dynamic mesh using `gl.drawArrays` with `gl.TRIANGLES`.
Now, to improve performance, I would like to move the drawing to WebAssembly.

Can I share the same WebGL context between WASM and Javascript, so I do my texture and shader loading on the JavaScript side, but my mesh generation and drawcalls on the WASM side?

If so, how (and where) should I create the context, and how do I pass handles for resources between the two?

Comment: Short answer no. The WebAssembly site will rely on JavaScript Wrapper functions to access the WebGL context. Most times it would be better to do the generation in WebAssembly and then load it with JavaScript from the exposed WebAssembly memory into the WebGL context and to the draw calls afterwards in JavaScript.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Lee. Strange. When reading in particular this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086424/create-textures-in-javascript-and-webgl-and-identify-them-in-webassembly)  and this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/WebAssembly/comments/n0fyy7/passing_webgl_handlers_between_js_and_wasm/), I get the sense that it _is_ possible to work on the same context. However, it is unclear to me how, and if it is a requirement to create the context on the WASM side.

Comment: in those cases the wrapper is auto generated.